# My roommate add some unknown liquid to my personal facial product

Tags: united-states

I live with one of my roommate, and one day I open my makeup cleaning oil I smell a strong smell of alcohol but I’m not sure what is that. I’m sure that someone add something in it but I’m not sure who is it, and I only live with one roommate. And my shampoo was also filled with unknown liquid, what could I do now! And I try using a little of these products and now my hair and face are in pain.

Comment: call the cops?  or talk to the roommate.  or both

Answer (score 0):

> what could I do now!

You need to call the police and not touch the product bottles, lest wrongdoers' fingerprints get wiped out. The severity of your pain might warrant medical examination that could be relevant for evidentiary purposes.

The penal code of any jurisdiction in the US addresses the intentional adulteration of chemicals. The General Attorney would decide whether to prosecute the matter. You could also sue in civil court, although at this point it seems premature to proceed without any evidence of who did it.